# Facial Recognition in Matlab/Python

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-recognition, face-recognition

I am new to facial recognition. I am working on a project in which I have a training database that only contains one image of the person (no duplication of different expressions/lighting etc, as seems to be the case a lot of places online) and then another image is sent to be compared against this database. I can't control the lighting/pose of the people in these pictures.

We have a school database of images and I am trying to make an app where you could take your picture and it would scan the school database and identify you. Currently I am using a [PCA script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17032-pca-based-face-recognition-system) in MATLAB, but it doesn't seem to work that well as it identifies the wrong person.

So I'm wondering is there a better way to do this given my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this [tutorial](http://www.shervinemami.co.cc/faceRecognition.html) and code on face recognition? It is implemented in OpenCV. And it will be easier to convert to python also as OpenCV got python API.

Or visit [face-rec.org](http://www.face-rec.org/source-codes/) for face recognition implementation using both Eigen faces method and Fisher faces method and also, all kinds of information on face recognition,data set etc.

Comment: [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/) is much easier than OpenCV, as the wrapper for `cv` is actually Pythonic. Check it out.